# How to track daily changes in an active record table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm getting crazy about a db design.
I'm writing a small app to collect and compare movies in some streaming services.

Basically every night I make some recursive call to the service's api, I get data from every movie in the catalogue and I update my db table "movie" using a method like this:

```
Movie.where(title: 'movie_title').find_or_create.update(attributes)
```

I want to track daily changes:

yesterday movie A, B & C in, movie E & H out
today movie X, Y in, movie B out

etc etc.

I think to add a "insertion_date" value for every db record, but of course is not easy to add the "remove_date".

Any idea for a better design?

Answer (score 0):

For tracking changes in your Movies table you could use the appropriate Rails callbacks:

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
   # after_create, after_update, after_destroy
end
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#available-callbacks

Comment: Audited track change in every record, but I need to track the changes for my table.

Comment: @RobertoPezzali see updated answer. In the `after_destroy` callback you could record the "remove_date"